# Can Bibulous be run from the terminal?

Tags: bibliographies, terminal-output, bibulous

I want to use [Bibulous](https://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/) to create custom bbl files. However, I don't use the programs for which Bibulous was designed to integrating with. Is it possible to run the program from the terminal? I would think this would be the simplest request but I can't find any information about how to do this. I would think it would be something like,

```
python bibulous.py mybib.bib
```

but I haven't been able to guess the right command...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That command is *almost* correct. What you need to run is

```
python bibulous.py mybib.aux
```

That is, the bibliography engine takes the `*.aux` file as its input, and generates the `*.bbl` as output.

Note that your system has to be able to find `bibulous.py` in order for this to work. If you want to use an absolute path to the file, you can try

```
python /path_to_file/bibulous.py mybib.aux
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for! If you have time, I have an unrelated question on Bibulous which I just posted, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334992/how-to-insert-new-line-in-bibulous-after-bibitem