# How to insert new line in bibulous after bibitem

Tags: bibliographies, bibulous

I would like to create a bbl file using Bibulous that consists of bibitem's separated by a line-break. I particular I'd like to have something of the form

```
\bibitem[1]{ref1}
Doe, J. {paper1} ...

\bibitem[2]{ref2}
Doe, J. {paper2} ...
```

(notice the extra space). Is there a way to implement this using Bibulous? This extra space is required when using the bibentry package.

Answer (score 3):

The hack for doing this is to change a line of code inside Bibulous, within the `write_bblfile()` function, from

```
filehandle.write((s + '\n').encode('utf-8'))
```

to

```
filehandle.write((s + '\n\n').encode('utf-8'))
```

This will add an extra newline after each entry. A better solution is not to need a hack in the first place, and I will get this change into the Bibulous code repository.

Comment: As of 2016-Dec-19, this double newline behavior is actually standard for Bibulous. The most recent version of bibulous.py includes the above "hack".